# How to "update" change_tracking setting to enable TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED

Tags: sql-server, change-tracking

I have a table where I have enabled change tracking without TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED. I know this because if I go through SSMS's Generate scripts, I get the line:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dt] ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH(TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = OFF)
```

I want to enable TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED. If I run:

```
ALTER TABLE dt
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING  
WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
```

I get error `Msg 4996, Level 16, State 1, Line 19
Change tracking is already enabled for table 'dt'.`

Do I have to disable change_tracking first? If so, is this explicitly documented somewhere?

Comment: Yes you have disable and enable. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51026077/disabling-column-updates-in-change-tracking

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable change_tracking first

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dt] DISABLE CHANGE_TRACKING
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dt] ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON)
```

Detail [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: this does not answer the question at all. I will mark this answer for deletion unless you edit it. the OP already does that and get an error message. His question is about how to fix it.

Comment: @MarcelloMiorelli I believe it is putting what was stated in the comment and link to SO into an answer. Change tracking needs to be disabled first, then enabled.

Comment: in that case it is a valid piece of info, just it lacked a bit on the communication side but all good now that you clarified.